# javascript "Export to Microsoft Excel" in IE6

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer-6

When right-licking on a HTML page in IE6 (our company standard), there is an option "Export to Microsoft Excel".  Can this option be fired via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot.  This is an IE addon installed by Excel and it has no public API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just for tables in web pages - if you want a page to automatically open in excel, you can just output the html table and set the mime type of the page to Excel.